# How to get developer console for Ipad

Tags: ipad

How to get developer console for Ipad. I am getting UI issues.

Comment: Connect IPad to Mac, Open Safari, Go to Developer, You should see your device under it, Click on index.html

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps :
1. Connect IPad to Mac
2. Open Safari
3. Go to Developer Tab
4. You should see your device under it
5. Click on index.html

[For more information click here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html)

[image: iPhone]